# How to open, read and store to DB content of XLSX file with PLSQL?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, plsql-package

I am trying to Open, Parse and save to Database the content from .xlsx file using PLSQL. Is this possible ? I have my files on the server, created the object for that path and gave rights rw for my user. Should I convert from XLSX to CSV using PLSQL? Is this possible or is there other way to deal with XLSX files ?

What I tried so far was [this](https://technology.amis.nl/2013/01/19/read-a-excel-xlsx-with-plsql/) but I get exception

> ORA-22288: file or LOB operation FILEOPEN failed

Tried to give rights on my object but it still not working.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you only want to upload a handful of spreadsheets manually (as opposed to requiring regular or high-volume automated uploads) then the simplest way to insert rows from an excel file into a database is add a column to the table which generates as SQL insert statement.

For example:

If the excel sheet has data in columns `A`, `B` and `C` and a header line:

```
ROWS A        B       C
1    id       value1  value2
2    1          23.0  Smith
3    2          42.7  O'Brien
4    3          59.6  Jones
```

Then in cell `D2` put:

```
="INSERT INTO table_name ("&A$1&","&B$1&","&C$1&") VALUES ("&A2&","&B2&",'"&SUBSTITUTE(C2,"'","''")&"');"
```

Then copy-and-paste the formula down into `D3-D4` so that the table looks like:

```
ROWS A      B       c        D
1    id     value1  value2  
2    1        23.0  Smith    INSERT INTO table_name (id,value1,value2) VALUES (1,23,'Smith');
3    2        42.7  O'Brien  INSERT INTO table_name (id,value1,value2) VALUES (2,42.7,'O''Brien');
4    3        59.6  Jones    INSERT INTO table_name (id,value1,value2) VALUES (3,59.6,'Jones');
```

Finally, copy the generated SQL statements and run it in SQL Plus.

Comment: I understand what are you saying but i don't have SQL Plus or Developer.

Comment: @AdiC.N. Then run those SQL statements in whatever IDE you would use to run the SQL statement you have linked to from your question. If you don't have any way to run SQL statements then any and all solutions we give you will be impossible to execute.